# ASP.NET disable authorization depending on host

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application and I have decorated my constroller/actions with Authorize attribute. In Startup.cs, I have defined the authentication like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

When I run my application in IIS or IIS Express, authorization works. However, I want to disable authorization when running in hosts that don't support Windows authentication like Console application.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
     if (!isWindowsAuthenticationSupported)
        options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
});
```

If this is the right approach, how would I set the isWindowsAuthenticationSupported variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to determine if Windows authentication is supported:

```
string iisHttpAuth = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_HTTPAUTH");
bool isWindowsAuthenticationSupported = false;
if (iisHttpAuth != null && iisHttpAuth.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("windows"))
    isWindowsAuthenticationSupported = true;
```